# FSTest - 'check default' spammed in logcat

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 SkyRocket SGH-I777 connected, via USB, to my development environment (Eclipse Juno SR1 with Android SDK 21.0.1 and ADT 21.1.0v20130207).

In LogCat, I'm seeing this FSTest "check default" message spammed thousands of times:

```
04-29 15:45:55.620: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(488): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 26 -88 10 96 2147483647 gsm|lte 4 level=4
04-29 15:45:55.630: E/AlarmManagerService(370): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 5151.571000000
04-29 15:45:55.810: D/FStest(686): check default
04-29 15:45:55.810: D/FStest(686): check default
04-29 15:45:56.821: D/FStest(686): check default
04-29 15:45:56.821: D/FStest(686): check default
04-29 15:45:56.901: W/SignalStrength(370): getLteLevel =4
04-29 15:45:56.901: W/SignalStrength(370): getLevel=4
```

It happens at least 2 times per second and sometimes as many as 6 or 8.  I have no idea what FSTest is or why it's checking my default.

Does anyone know what this is, what app it belongs to, or what it's trying to do?

Comment: Through System->Applications->Running, I have tried killing every running app and service that it will let me kill, to no avail.  This message is still occurring.

Comment: I have also rooted my phone and experimented with deleting all of the junkware that comes installed on this thing.  Still happening.

Answer (score 3):

Some internal/external app may be causing this message to be dumped every few seconds.

As a work-around, you can prevent this message by creating a new filter in LogCat.

Use the option to filter "**by Log Tag**" with the following regex
**^((?!FStest).)*$**

This will show all messages except the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue on a Samsung Galaxy SII running android 4.0.3.

It occurs whether I have wifi on or off.